# What emits the least radiation when hot?

Tags: temperature, electromagnetic-radiation

What element with a high vapor point the emits to least light or radiation when heated to its vapor pressure point in a vacuum?

Ideally I would like to know in 0 gravity and 0 pressure which elements can be get the hottest around the sun before the vapor pressure point is reached and/or emit the least black body radiation when hot.

https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/shielding-capability-of-liquid-metals

Comment: The black body radiation from all elements and compounds is the same.

Comment: i suppose an isolated proton wouldn't

Comment: As for A.K. comment: your question should be what ensemble of matter does not emit EM radiation (or Vis, depending on your exact meaning) when hot? Then the answer is in the comment by Karl. (Dark matter not considered as for no chemistry can be done ;)

Comment: @Alchimista is this better?

Comment: Say substance, so you get rid of the fact that atoms/molecules can't have a T and a vapour pressure. Hot atoms are at best moving faster. But you got an answer so.... Referring to a limit made the Q interesting.

Comment: Emissions of radiations depends on elementary particles, so NOT on molecular structure. As Karl said, it depends on "black body radiation". So, please, stop up-voting that inept answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, a smooth or molten, unoxidized metal surface (regardless of chemistry) makes a good candidate.  [This thesis from Auburn University](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://etd.auburn.edu/bitstream/handle/10415/1395/TEODORESCU_GEORGE_46.pdf%3Fsequence%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwjW7cCwwM3hAhVLMawKHVYYClsQFjAKegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0vaTPfk2IEPTbU45_qR4GW) reports the emissivities of both oxidized and unoxidized metals at temperatures typically encountered in industrial processes; note the low values for all the unoxidized metals studied in the IR range where most radiation is given off.

Comment: Yes but mecury has a low evaporation point.

Comment: @Muze — But the state does not matter in emitting electromagnetic waves!

Comment: @Steffi can you please explain more in an answer for a Layman like myself can understand.

Comment: Will anyone please tell me what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I thought maybe @SteffX would have went more into detail with an answer but he didn't. I think your answer is good. Tks

Comment: @Muze — To my knowledge, any fundamental particle emits light when accelerated BUT acceleration in its broadest sense can mean either increasing or decreasing the speed OR changing direction (this property is used to generate X-rays). So any atom will radiate as much as its fundamental particles (black body radiation as Karl said). And there is no point about asking about "hot" compounds (how hot?) with a "high vapor pressure" in deep space.

Comment: @SteffX At what point does iron start to emit xrays before reaching it vapor point? I should have said element and not substance.